# How to implement return codes in DdeCallback function

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dde

What is the correct way to write `DdeCallback` function? To be more precise, I'm talking about return codes.

From the official [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms648742(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The return value depends on the transaction class. For more
>   information about the return values, see descriptions of the
>   individual transaction types

For example, my application need to handle `XTYP_ADVDATA` messages by itself and ignore the others.

So, according to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms648714(v=vs.85).aspx) for `XTYP_ADVDATA`, I need to return `DDE_FACK` if I processed this message:

> A DDE callback function should return DDE_FACK if it processes this
>   transaction, DDE_FBUSY if it is too busy to process this transaction,
>   or DDE_FNOTPROCESSED if it rejects this transaction

But what about the other messages? What should I return in the other cases?

// Initialization

```
DWORD id_inst = 0;
UINT res = DdeInitializeA(
  &id_inst,
  (PFNCALLBACK)DdeCallback,
  APPCLASS_STANDARD | APPCMD_CLIENTONLY,
  0 // Reserved; must be set to zero
);

// XTYP_ADVSTART

HDDEDATA data = DdeClientTransaction(
  NULL,   // The beginning of the data the client must pass to the server. This parameter is required only if the wType parameter is XTYP_EXECUTE or XTYP_POKE. Otherwise, this parameter should be NULL
  0,      // The length, in bytes, of the data pointed to by the pData parameter
  conv,
  item,
  CF_TEXT,
  XTYP_ADVSTART,
  30000,  // The maximum amount of time, in milliseconds, that the client will wait for a response from the server application in a synchronous transaction
  NULL    // A pointer to a variable that receives the result of the transaction. An application that does not check the result can use NULL for this value
);
```

```
HDDEDATA CALLBACK DdeCallback(
  UINT uType,     // The transaction type
  UINT uFmt,      // The format atom of the data sent from the server
  HCONV hconv,    // A handle to the conversation
  HSZ hsz1,       // A handle to the topic name
  HSZ hsz2,       // A handle to the item name
  HDDEDATA hdata, // A handle to the data associated with the topic name and item name pair
  DWORD dwData1,  // Not used
  DWORD dwData2)  // Not used
{
  switch (uType)
  {
  case XTYP_ADVDATA:
    DWORD data_size = DdeGetData(hdata, NULL, 0, 0);
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[data_size]);
    DdeGetData(
      hdata,
      (BYTE *)buf.get(),
      data_size,
      0 // An offset within the DDE object. Data is copied from the object beginning at this offset
    );
    std::cout << "Data received: " << buf.get() << std::endl;
    return (HDDEDATA)DDE_FACK;
  }

  return /* ??? */;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You receive only the type of messages that you register for (or more accurately, that you do not filter away) when calling `DdeInitialize()`.  If you only register to receive (or not ignore) `XTYP_ADVDATA` messages, that is all you will receive, and you don't have to worry about handling the other message types.  Any message type that you do not filter away MUST be handled correctly in your callback, accordingly to the rules of each message type.

Read the documentation for [`DdeInitialize()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648757.aspx), paying attention to the description for its `afCmd` parameter.  Also read the documentation about DDE's [Basic Concepts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648768.aspx), in particular the sections describing [Initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648768.aspx#_win32_Initialization) and the [Callback function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648768.aspx#_win32_Callback_Function).

Comment: "If you only register to receive (or not ignore) XTYP_ADVDATA messages, that is all you will receive" -- are you sure? Because I tried to print `uType` for every message that I receive in this callback and I noticed that I've got two additional message types when I disable DDE server

Comment: You are obviously not disabling everything that you want to ignore. But you did not specify which other messages you are actually receiving, or show your actual code that is calling `DdeInitialize()`.

Comment: http://pastie.org/10528362. I receive messages with types 32978 and 32962 when I shutdown the DDE server

Comment: Those messages are `XTYP_UNREGISTER` and `XTYP_DISCONNECT`. Your call to `DdeInitialize()` needs to include the the `CBF_SKIP_DISCONNECTS` and `CBF_SKIP_UNREGISTRATIONS` flags to avoid those messages.

Comment: And then there's no other messages than `XTYP_ADVDATA`, right?

Comment: Yes, you have to disable any messages you are not interested in, otherwise you have to handle them. Read the documentation.